# change an image this is not shown

Tags: android, eclipse

I have my android project with ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders.

The device I'm testing is hdpi, so, I deleted an image in hdpi folder and add a new one with the same name into this folder.

But now the image is not shown. I didnt change the code.

I tried cleaning the project, restarting eclipse and restarting the computer, but the problem is there.

Any other action I should try?

Comment: Have you refreshed the folders in eclipse? Right click and refresh.

Comment: I did! before cleaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded!! the problem was the image, it was CMYK instead of RGB.